Inconsistency in number of cheeses per box in Elsschot's "Cheese"
In Chapter 10 of Willem Elsschot's Cheese, the narrator Laarmans takes delivery of "three hundred and seventy patent boxes" full of cheese. He decides:

I'll sell in multiples of twenty-seven cheeses, as there are twenty-seven cheeses in each box.
Elsschot, Willem. Cheese. 1933. Trans. Paul Vincent. London: Granta, 2002. p. 64.

He also arranges to have one of the boxes sent to his home so that he can have samples of the cheese for potential customers. Yet in the next chapter, the box delivered to his home has a different number of cheeses in it:

A heavy case containing twenty-six cheeses, each weighing two kilos, plus packaging. Sixty kilos all told.
ibid., p. 66.

This inconsistency is puzzling. What is the explanation?
In the previous chapter, it is established that one of the patent boxes has been broken open at customs and one of the cheeses removed, but there is no indication that this is the box that gets sent on to Laarmans' home. Indeed, he has a difficult time of it opening the case, suggesting it is intact:

I tried shifting it, but couldn't.
The only thing for it was to get a crowbar.
And then I started hammering until the house shook, and my wife came upstairs to see if she could help me. ... after taking a break I managed to get one plank loose. I don't know what's patent about them but they are certainly sturdy cases.
ibid., pp. 66–67.

So it does not seem that the inconsistency can be explained away by saying that the box Laarmans receives at his house is the one opened at customs, but I can't see any other explanation either.

As I read it, he has 370 boxes, each with 27 cheeses.  So he is proposing to sell them by the boxful.

@mikado oh yes of course, duh. Edited. Thanks for pointing that out!

Elsschot wrote Kaas / Cheese" in just two weeks [van de Reijt: 116], so it is at least plausible that the author made an error here. However, there is no need to assume that Elsschot was inconsistent. Each box contains 27 cheeses, but as the employees of the Blauwhoedenveem (where the cheeses are stored) explain, one box was opened by the customs agency (chapter 10; Elsschot: 462):

De laatste kist was opengebroken. Door de douane, zei de man van't veem. En die hadden een van mijn kazen middendoor gesneden. De ene helft ontbrak en ik vroeg waar die gebleven was.
'Weet u dan niet, mijnheer, dat zij he recht hadden die driehonderd zeventig kisten een voor een open te breken? Wij hadden de waarde van die doorgesneden bol door de douane kunnen doen vergoeden, mijnheer, maar ik heb de helft aan de commies cadeau gegeven en daardoor voor Hornstra drieduizend frank aan rechten uitgespaard, (…).

Translation:

The last box had been broken open. Through customs, said the man from the warehouse. And they had cut one of my cheeses in half. One half was missing and I asked where it had gone.
'Don't you know, sir, that they had the right to break open those three hundred and seventy boxes one by one? We could have had the value of that cut cheese ball reimbursed by customs, sir, but I gave half of it to the officer as a gift and thus saved Hornstra three thousand francs in duties (...).

After that, Laarmans gives the other half of that cheese to the office (page 463):

Na die man het restant van de bol en een royale fooi gegeven te hebben, (…) beval ik hem mijn kazen nog eens warm aan (…).

Translation:

After giving the man the remainder of the cheese ball and a generous tip, (…) I recommended my cheeses to him again (…).

The next chapter, chapter 11, mentions the number of cheeses in the box sent to Laarmans's house two times; there can be no mistake about the number of cheeses in it: twenty six. The reason is not stated explicitly, but the employees of the Blauwhoedenveem sent the box that had been opened by customs to Laarmans's house. As mentioned in chapter 10, one half of a cheese had been given to a customs officer, the other half to the Blauwhoedenveem employee. So there were just 26 cheeses left in the box. And apparently, the box had been properly closed again before sending it to Laarmans's house, which explains why Laarmans has difficulty opening it again.
Sources:

Ellschot, Willem: Verzameld werk. Bezorgd en toegelicht door Peter de Bruijn. Amsterdam: Athenaeum—Polak & Van Gennep, 2005. (This edition of Elsschot's collected works is 851 pages long and is virtually complete; only some poems and stories were not included.)
Van de Reijt, Vic: De ontdekking van Elsschot. Amsterdam: Athenaeum—Polak & Van Gennep, 2019.

PS: According to Wiktionary, the Dutch word veem is recognised only by 52% of people in the Netherlands and by 27% of people in Flanders. I have never encountered it outside Elsschot's novel Kaas / Cheese.

Thanks for this answer, but as I explained in the question, I don't think this is plausible. A box that the customs office had already opened would not be so difficult to open again. That Laarmans is struggling with the patented crate is also made clear in chapter 11, and there's nothing to indicate that the crate has been opened and re-sealed.

@verbose It's the only explanation that makes sense. It is the only box that has only 26 cheeses. In addition, those are wooden boxes that were nailed shut; after all, this is the 1930s: these box or crates are mode of wood.
